# How can I access values within Optional NSSingleObjectArrayI?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I do not know how to access the 'duration' value within my nested Optional NSSingleObjectArrayI that is constructed from a JSON response. How do I access the nested values within this data structure?

When I call print(firstRow["elements"]), I get the following output:

```
Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x60000120f920>(
{
    distance = {
        text = "1.8 km";
        value = 1754;
    };
    duration = {
        text = "5 mins";
        value = 271;
    };
    "duration_in_traffic" = {
        text = "4 mins";
        value = 254;
    };
    status = OK;
}
))
```

I have tried string indexing (firstRow['elements']['duration']) but am getting errors.

```swift
fetchData { (dict, error) in
    if let rows = dict?["rows"] as? [[String:Any]]{
        if let firstRow = rows[0] as? [String:Any]{
            print("firstRow is")
            print(firstRow["elements"])
            // Trying to access duration within firstRow['elements'] here           
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, this is the fetchData function:

```
func fetchData(completion: @escaping ([String:Any]?, Error?) -> Void) {

    let url = getRequestURL(origin: "test", destination: "test")!;

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            if let array = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:Any]{
                completion(array, nil)
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
            completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

A sample HTTP JSON request is here:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=77%20Massachusetts%20Ave,%20Cambridge,%20MA&departure_time=now&key=AIzaSyB65D4XHv6PkqvWJ7C-cFvT1QHi9OkqGCE&origins=428%20Memorial%20Dr,%20Cambridge,%20MA
```

Comment: Could you add original json and parse code please? So, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Also could you try to unwrap your array first? For example like this: firstRow['elements'][0]['duration'] or firstRow['elements'].first['duration']

Comment: Use Codable, not JSONSerialization.

Comment: @matt Can you kindly elaborate? I am not very familiar with Codable.

Comment: @AntonVlasov I tried that and got nil :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing your output, your `firstRow["elements"]` is Optional, so you need to unwrap it. And it actually is an NSArray with a single element, where the only element is a Dictionary, with 4 entries -- "distance", "duration", "duration_in_traffic" and "status". You may need to cast the element to a Dictionary to access each entry.

You may use Optional binding with `as?`-casting for this purpose:

```
fetchData { (dict, error) in
    if let rows = dict?["rows"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        if let firstRow = rows.first {
            print("firstRow is")
            print(firstRow["elements"])
            //Unwrap and cast `firstRow["elements"]`.
            if let elements = firstRow["elements"] as? [[String: Any]] {
                //The value for "duration" is a Dictionary, you need to cast it again.
                if let duration = elements.first?["duration"] as? [String: Any] {
                    print(duration["text"] as? String)
                    print(duration["value"] as? Int)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or too deeply nested `if`s are hard to read, so someone would like it as:

```
fetchData { (dict, error) in
    if
        let rows = dict?["rows"] as? [[String: Any]],
        let firstRow = rows.first,
        let elements = firstRow["elements"] as? [[String: Any]],
        let duration = elements.first?["duration"] as? [String: Any]
    {
        print(duration["text"] as? String)
        print(duration["value"] as? Int)
    }
}
```

Or using `guard` may be a better solution.

---

Or else, if you can show us the whole JSON text in a readable format, someone would show you how to use Codable, which is a modern way to work with JSON in Swift.

Comment: Thank you! I implemented Codeable and got my Codeable classes very easily through http://swiftjson.com

Comment: @Willy, seems you have found a pretty site to work with `Codable`. Happy coding.