# How to get value from Optional(Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI >(25)))

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to get the value of "price" key which is "25"

I am getting this response Json From Backend

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Request successfully served.",
  "data": {
    "games": {
      "TWELVEBYTWENTYFOUR": {
        "jackpot_amount": "KES 40,000.00",
        "draw_date": "2021-05-21 10:59:45",
        "extra": {
          "jackpotAmount": 40000,
          "unitCostJson": [
            {
              "currency": "KES",
              "price": 25
            }
          ]
        },
      }
    },
    "currentTime": {
      "date": "2021-05-20 22:28:18.738038"
    }
  }
}
```

This is my code so far :

```
fetchData { (dict, error) in

    let playerLoginInfo = dataDict["data"] as? NSDictionary
    let playerGameInfo = playerLoginInfo?.value(forKey: "games") as? NSDictionary
    
    if let TWELVEBYTWENTYFOUR = playerGameInfo?.value(forKey: "TWELVEBYTWENTYFOUR") as? NSDictionary {

            let extra = TWELVEBYTWENTYFOUR.value(forKey: "extra") as? NSDictionary
            let unitCostJson = extra?.value(forKey: "unitCostJson") as? NSArray
            print("price")
            print(unitCostJson?.value(forKey: "price") as? Any)

    }
}
```

I get this is console :

```
Optional(Optional(<__NSSingleObjectArrayI 0x600001f091d0>(
25
)
))
```

I have seen this question [How can I access values within Optional NSSingleObjectArrayI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522572/how-can-i-access-values-within-optional-nssingleobjectarrayi) but I couldn't figure out a solution

Edit:

I have now used Codeable to get data:

```
struct Resp: Codable {
    let errorCode: Int
    let message: String
    let data: Dat
}
struct Dat: Codable {
    let games: Games
    let currentTime: CurrentTime
}

struct Games: Codable {
    let game_code: String
    let datetime: String
    let estimated_jackpot: String
    let guaranteed_jackpot: String
    let jackpot_title: String
    let jackpot_amount: String
    let draw_date: String
    let extra: Extra
    let next_draw_date: String
    let active: String
}
struct Extra: Codable {
    let currentDrawNumber: Int
    let currentDrawFreezeDate: String
    let currentDrawStopTime: String
    let jackpotAmount: Int
    let unitCostJson: [UnitCostJson]
}
struct UnitCostJson: Codable {
    let currency: String
    let price: Int
}

struct CurrentTime: Codable {
    let date: String
    let timezone_type: Int
    let timezone: String
}
```

I'm trying to get value from price now with this code

```
    do{
        let resp:Resp = try JSONDecoder().decode(Resp.self , from:data);
        let data = resp.data
        let games = data.games
        let extra = games.extra
        let unitCostJson = extra.unitCostJson
        print(unitCostJson[0].price) 
    }
    catch{
        GlobalFunctions.shared.callOnMainThread {
            self.showAlert(Message: "Something went wrong. Please retry.")
        }
    }
```

It is going into `catch`
How should I get the data inside on the unitCostJson now??

Comment: In swift, don't use `NS...` data types, use their swift native equivalents. But don't do that either. Create `Codable` structs to represent your data and use `JSONDecoder`.

Comment: You try to get a value from an array as if it was a dictionary. First get first element of the nsarray then try to get value for key price

Comment: How to get value from Array

Comment: Use Codable to decode the json and you won't need this cumbersome code logic with casting to dictionaries and arrays.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have used `Codable` now as you suggested but not able to get value.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have used Codable Please check edited question

Comment: Good but then you have mostly solved the problem right? `let unitCost = result.data.games.extra.unitCostJson`

Comment: Change the catch by adding `print(error)` to see what's going wrong. It looks to me like you have added a lot of properties that is not part of the json, remove them or use CodingKeys

Comment: I got this: 
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "game_code", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "data", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "games", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"game_code\", intValue: nil) (\"game_code\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I butchered your struct and removed any irrelevant properties (compared to the json), if you want to add them back then you need to use an CodingKey enum

```
struct Resp: Codable {
    let errorCode: Int
    let message: String
    let data: Dat
}
struct Dat: Codable {
    let games: [String:Games]
    let currentTime: CurrentTime
}

struct Games: Codable {
    let extra: Extra
}
struct Extra: Codable {

    let unitCostJson: [UnitCostJson]
}
struct UnitCostJson: Codable {
    let currency: String
    let price: Int
}

struct CurrentTime: Codable {
    let date: String
}
```

Now you can access the unitCost like this

```
let unitCost = resp.data.games["TWELVEBYTWENTYFOUR"]?.extra.unitCostJson
```

Comment: How did you initialize `result` variable ?

Comment: I am getting this error in catch `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "games", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"games\", intValue: nil) (\"games\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: I changed from result to resp, they are the same.  I don’t understand the second issue

Comment: I am now back at my computer and have double checked the code I posted and it works as expected.